# How to serialize object to json based on the client culture with newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter and .NET Framework 4.7.2.

I have a controller that returns an object with a property of type LocalizedString which is just a simple object with 2 properties: english and french representation of a string.

The culture is set to the current thread by the controller like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(this.Name);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(this.Name);
```

The culture comes from the request cookies and when queried within the controller GET method it works.

The LocalizedString has a ToString method that looks like this:

```
public string ToString(string language)
{
   return language.Equals(Language.English.CultureName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? this.English : this.French;
}
```

Now I have a JsonConverter to manage the serialization of the LocalizedString objects that looks like this:

```
public class LocalizedStringJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the JSON representation of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The <see cref="T:Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter"/> to write to.</param><param name="value">The value.</param><param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((LocalizedString)value).ToString(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads the JSON representation of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader">The <see cref="T:Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader"/> to read from.</param><param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param><param name="existingValue">The existing value of object being read.</param><param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The object value.
    /// </returns>
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this instance can convert the specified object type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// <c>true</c> if this instance can convert the specified object type; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(LocalizedString);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

When I query the culture within the JsonConverter like this:
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name

The value is always the culture of the server (which is french when i debug on my PC).

I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong...
I know of plenty of other ways to do what I want to do, like I could let client manage the culture with javascript or my controller could actually return a string pre-localized but that would mean I would need to refactor the whole web app.. which I'm trying to avoid.

Thanks for your time

**UPDATE**

I've tried to add my own filter to make sure the culture is still set after my controller returns but the JsonConverter is executed after the OnActionExecuted method of my filter and the culture is still wrong. I don't know what calls the JsonConverter but that is probably where the culture should be set...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone encounters the same problem I couldn't find the exact answer I was looking for. I was looking for a way to either pass the request itself to the JsonConverter or set the culture info of the thread that is running the JsonConverter.

Couldn't find anything in the available documentation so my workaround is a filter that sets culture info to every LocalizedString of the Response Content. Note that the IsValueType() method is an extension method that is basically return type.IsValueType || type == typeof(string);

```
/// <summary>
/// Assign the culture to every LocalizedString from the response.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class SetCultureToLocalizedStringsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs after the action method is invoked
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionExecutedContext"></param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override async Task OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var content = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content != null ? await actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>(cancellationToken) : null;

        AssignCultureOfLocalizedStringProperties(
            content,
            typeof(LocalizedString)
                .GetProperties().First(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(CultureInfo)),
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
    }

    private static void AssignCultureOfLocalizedStringProperties(object obj, PropertyInfo cultureProperty, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (obj == null || obj.GetType().IsValueType())
        {
            return;
        }

        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(LocalizedString))
        {
            cultureProperty.SetValue(obj, culture);
            return;
        }

        var currentProperties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (var property in currentProperties)
        {
            var propValue = property.GetValue(obj);

            if (property.PropertyType.IsValueType())
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (propValue is IEnumerable elems)
            {
                foreach (var item in elems)
                {
                    AssignCultureOfLocalizedStringProperties(item, cultureProperty, culture);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                AssignCultureOfLocalizedStringProperties(propValue, cultureProperty, culture);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I had to change some code of my LocalizedString class. First I've added a CultureInfo property

```
    [Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
    public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }
```

And I've also changed the toString method.

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.IsEnglish() ? this.English : this.French;
    }

    private bool IsEnglish()
    {
        var cultureName = this.Culture != null ? this.Culture.Name : Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;

        return cultureName.Equals(Language.English.CultureName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [How a Thread's Culture Is Determined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.8#how-a-threads-culture-is-determined) your code should work if you set the culture correctly.

What is `Console.WriteLine("CurrentCulture is now {0}.", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);` just before you return from your controller (so just before the serialiser is called)?

Also, the Microsoft [doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) states:

> In the .NET Framework 4.5.2 and earlier versions, the *CurrentCulture* property is read-only; that is, you can retrieve the property value, but you cannot set it. To change the current culture, you assign the `CultureInfo` object that represents the new culture to the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` property. Starting with the .NET Framework 4.6, the *CurrentCulture* property is read-write; you can both set and retrieve the property's value. If you do set the property value to a *CultureInfo* object that represents a new culture, the value of the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` property also changes.

Comment: It is "en-CA" just before the return line and then "fr-CA" within the WriteJson method of my converter. Could there be a filter or something that changes the culture between the time the controller returns its value and the time the JsonConverter writes the content?

Comment: What if you call `var temp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject` explicitly, just as a test, just before you return? What does `WriteJson` see then?

Comment: Also, what happens if you set `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("th-TH", false);` (not `Thread.CurrentThread.`) - there should be no difference in you scenario, but maybe I'm reading the docs incorrectly. It's worth a try.

Comment: When i use my custom JsonConverter on a LocalizedString in my controller it uses the CurrentCulture as expected.

Comment: I still have the same results with System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = . Btw, thanks for taking the time to think about it! It seems the json serialization is started on another thread which doesn't carry the previous culture... I can't find any documention on how to manage the culture when serializing. I only need to have a handle on the request so I can fetch the user culture from the headers...